# Context menu and the selection of the word under cursor in VBA for Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am building a Microsoft Word 2013 macro in VBA. I want to pass the word under the cursor to my VBA macro when the user hits CTRL+SPACE. My function will process the word and will produce five or six options like intellisense in a context menu.

I am unable to find any property for the objection Selection that produces the word under cursor. Can anyone please guide how to get the word under the cursor and produce a context menu?

Comment: The answer seems to be quite easy when you want to get 'word under the cursor':  `Selection.Words(1).Text`

Comment: @KazJaw Thanks. Do you have any thoughts about the context menu. I am almost near to creating a context menu, but don't know how to programmatically make it visible as the user types a word.